# Getting WIFI Signal strength in iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi

I know this is a duplicate of many similar questions.But none of them were clear they where not giving proper solutions.My question is how to get WiFi signal strength in iOS devices?. I know it has done using Private API's but I don't know how to use?. Please can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

For ios9+

Register your app as Hotspot helper. ([forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657](http://forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657))

```
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>

for(NEHotspotNetwork *hotspotNetwork in [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]) {
    NSString *ssid = hotspotNetwork.SSID;
    NSString *bssid = hotspotNetwork.BSSID;
    BOOL secure = hotspotNetwork.secure;
    BOOL autoJoined = hotspotNetwork.autoJoined;
    double signalStrength = hotspotNetwork.signalStrength;
}
```

Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971064/988169

Comment: So pre iOS 9 ,pinging mechanism is the only way to go I guess

Comment: The signal strength returned is a percentage value between 0.0 to 1.0. How to efficiently convert this value to dBs or dBm?

Answer (score 0):

Apple restrict (wireless private api)  to use private api to find the strenth of wifi .