# Is it possible to get wifi signal strength in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, ios9

I want to check WIFI signal strength to display some kind of message for weak WIFI signal.

I fount that it is not possible in iOS 8 and older.

Is it possible to get wifi signal strength in iOS 9? and if answer is yes then How?

Answer (score 8):

Yes , it is possible in iOS 9.Look into **NEHotspotNetwork**

[image]

Comment: The signal strength returned is a percentage value between 0.0 to 1.0. How to efficiently convert this value to dBs or dBm?

Comment: Can we test signal strength of cellular network with NEHotspotNetwork if not please suggest how to check signal strength on cellular network. thanks

Comment: First, register your app as Hotspot helper. (forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657)

Answer (score 7):

Register your app as Hotspot helper. ([forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657](http://forums.developer.apple.com/message/30657#30657))

```
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>

for(NEHotspotNetwork *hotspotNetwork in [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]) {
    NSString *ssid = hotspotNetwork.SSID;
    NSString *bssid = hotspotNetwork.BSSID;
    BOOL secure = hotspotNetwork.secure;
    BOOL autoJoined = hotspotNetwork.autoJoined;
    double signalStrength = hotspotNetwork.signalStrength;
}
```

Comment: The signal strength returned is a percentage value between 0.0 to 1.0. How to efficiently convert this value to dBs or dBm?

Comment: Can we test signal strength of cellular network with NEHotspotNetwork if not please suggest how to check signal strength on cellular network. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is, but you need permission from Apple. Once Apple allows you to use the HotspotHelper framework, you'll be able to create profiles with the hotspot helper entitlements. Check this post: [How to get Wifi SSID in iOS9 after CaptiveNetwork is deprecated and calls for Wifi name are already blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-depracted-and-calls-for-wif/31590787#31590787)